# Combining multiple IndexOf

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Is there a way to combine multiple indexOf() to make this more succinct?

```
Dim UserAgent As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent

If Not (UserAgent.IndexOf("Chrome") > -1) OrElse Not (UserAgent.IndexOf("Safari") > -1) Then

    ' do this

End If
```

Comment: The condition seems to be odd. Do you really want to check if it not contains chrome or(if it contains chrome) if it does not contain safari? I assume that you want to use `AndAlso` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Contains` instead of `IndexOf` and a collection to lookup:

```
Dim browsers = {"Chrome", "Safari"}
if Not browsers.Any(Function(b) UserAgent.Contains(b)) Then

End If
```

or with query syntax:

```
Dim matchingBrowsers = From browser In browsers
                       Where UserAgent.Contains(browser)
If Not matchingBrowsers.Any() Then

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex `(Chrome|Safari)`
Not familiar with VB but it should be similar to `if (Regex.Match(@"(Chrome|Safari)") != null)`